# String manipulating in python

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to make a function that will take a string an remove any blocks of text from it. For example turning "(example) somestuff" into "somestuff" removing any blocked text from the string. This is a single function for a large program that is meant to automatically create directories based on the files name and move relevant files into said folder. I think I'm running into an endless loop but lost as to what by problem is.

```
startbrackets = '[', '('
endbrackets = ']', ')'
digits = range(0,10)

def striptoname(string):
    startNum = 0
    endNum = 0
    finished = True
    indexBeginList = []
    indexEndList = [] 

    while (finished):
        try:
            for bracket in startbrackets:
                indexBeginList.append(string.find(bracket, 0, len(string)))
        except:
            print "Search Start Bracket Failed"
            wait()
            exit()

        # Testing Code START
        finished = False
        for i in indexBeginList:
            if i != -1:
                finished = True
                startNum = i
                break
        # Testing Code END

        try:
            for bracket in endbrackets:
                indexEndList.append(string.find(bracket, 0, len(string)))
        except:
            print "Search End Bracket Failed"
            wait()
            exit()

        # Testing Code START
        for i in indexEndList:
            if i != -1:
                endNum = i
                break
        # Testing Code END

        if(finished):
            if(startNum == 0):
                string = string[:(endNum+1)]
            else:
                string = string[0:startNum]
    for i in digits:
        string.replace(str(i),"")
    return string
```

Comment: are you allowed to use `regex`?

Comment: Is the "(example)" the same thing in every case or does the user need the ability to set "(example)" each time and then get what ever is after "(example)"?

Comment: Sorry guess i wasn't very clear everything the the " was meant as a sample input..... another example would be "[asdf] (ahgf) tada 5084". My program is trying to turn it into "tada" removeing any text inside brackets or numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
import re

def remove_unwanted(s):
    # This will look for a group of any characters inside () or [] and substitute an empty string, "", instead of that entire group.
    # The final strip is to eliminate any other empty spaces that can be leftover outside of the parenthesis.
    return re.sub("((\(|\[).*(\)|\]))", "", s).strip()

print(remove_unwanted("[some text] abcdef"))
>>> "abcdef"
print(remove_unwanted("(example) somestuff"))
>>> "somestuff"
```